# how to speed up writing into the serial port in Linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, real-time, low-latency

I have written a simple program that writes into the serial port (blockingly) and measures the time it takes. writing 104 Bytes of data @ 19200 takes 58/59 msec.

Reading the same amount of data takes only 54 msec (making a simple math shows that 54 msec is the correct number).

How can i reduce the latency of writing into the serialport?? By the way my hardware is a Beagle Bone Black. My code follows:

```
QTime t;t.start();
int bytes_written = write(m_serialport_fd, data, data_size);
if(bytes_written != data_size)
   //handle error
tcdrain(m_serialport_fd);
qDebug()<<"Writing into serialport took" << t.elapsed();
```

Any hints is appreciated.

Comment: Is it using DMA or not? Disable it. Then, set IRQ affinity to most idling CPU. Disable any runtime power management.

Comment: @ 0andriy: Thanks for the reply but how can i do the steps you have proposed? My program is a normal process.